# Instantaneous value of angular momentum

Tags: angular-momentum

I am trying to smooth the torque ripples of a shaft by placing on it a unsymmetrical flywheel (having great diameter in positions where torque is low and small one where the torque is great). I have the analytical equation of the torque versus time and/or angular position. To calculate the shape of the flywheel I should need to know the way to compute the instantaneous value of angular momentum (vs. time or angular position).

Thank you in advance for your kind response.

Answer (score 1):

Since $Torque = I*\alpha$ you can iteratively solve for the required moment of intertia, $I$, using the required torque and the angular acceleration, $\alpha$.

If doing this by hand, just model it as a series of spokes with adjustable weights at the end.  For example, when balancing old-fashioned crank shafts, the mechanic would pound lead slugs of one of several standard sizes into the inner or outer ring of holes; after a few tries, the experienced mechanic got the system balanced.

Comment: If your question is answered, click the up arrow next to the answer, and the answered button. Post a comment when you have tried it out.